# refresh header component after login using angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular

actually i am using angular 11 and i want to show username in header component but my header is load first then my login component is load so after loading login component data store in local storage that why when i refresh page then user name is show but i dont want refresh page so what can i do for that please help me

below code is my authservice

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }
  loginUser(data: {}) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'signin', data)
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    //console.log(localStorage.getItem('user_details'))
    if (localStorage.getItem('user_details') !== undefined && localStorage.getItem('user_details') !== null) {
      //console.log("if")
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
    //return !!localStorage.getItem('user_details')
  }
  getUserName(): any {
    const userName = localStorage.getItem('user_details');
    if (userName) {
      return JSON.parse(userName);
    }
    return false;
  }
  isLoggedOut() {
    localStorage.removeItem('user_details');
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
}
```

this is my header component

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../login/services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  scrolled: boolean = false;
  userName: string = '';
  fname: string = '';
  lname: string = "";

  @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
  onWindowScroll() {
    this.scrolled = window.scrollY > 1;
  }
  constructor(public auth: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.auth.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
    }
    const user = this.auth.getUserName();
    this.userName = user.role_name;
    this.fname = user.first_name.charAt(0);
    this.lname = user.last_name.charAt(0);
  }

  logOut() {
    localStorage.removeItem('user_details');
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
}
```

below is login component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Md5 } from 'md5-typescript';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm: any;
  data: any;
  success: any;
  message: any;

  constructor( private auth: AuthService, private router: Router ) {

    this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[\\w-\\.]+@([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]{2,4}$')]),
      password: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.loginForm.value);
    let data = {
      "email_id": this.loginForm.value.email,
      "password": Md5.init(this.loginForm.controls['password'].value)
    }
    this.auth.loginUser(data).subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        this.data == response;
        this.success == response.success;
        if (response.success == 1) {
          localStorage.setItem("user_details", JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(response.data).user_details))
          console.log(localStorage.getItem('user_details'));
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        } else {
          this.message = response.message;
        }
      }
    );
    this.loginForm.reset();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please make a observable in header components. when value updates, It will automatically populate the username

Comment: You make auth service getUserName method should be observable and subscribe in header components. It will work

Comment: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/10/angular-8-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can't use local storage to get logged in user details, because you component is already loaded. You need to create shared service using Subject or [Behaviorsubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject) (RXJS operatoer) You can find example https://medium.com/@hitensharma1515/sharing-data-between-components-using-service-2d662a653a89

Comment: i try to do this but i got error can someone  share code with me how to do using with sharedservice